# Centering a Javascript-added Image

Tags: html, css, html-table, centering

I am unable to center the Javascript-added image within a table with my embedded CSS.  Please let me know how to fix the CSS so that the image in the table is centered.  I tried setting the margin property to auto for the image, but the image in the table does not center.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Today's Events at the TRU Union</title>
    <style>
        p {text-align: center;}
        table {display: block; margin: auto;}
        body img{display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
        h2 {text-align: center; color: red;}
    </style>

</head>
<body background="Back01.jpg" text="black">
    <div id="table"></div>
</body>
<script>
        function determine_picture_day_and_month(){
            var table_content = insert_table();
            table_content += insert_title_rules_and_image();
            return table_content;
        }

        function insert_table(){
            var daily_images = ["Weekend.gif", "Monday.gif", "Tuesday.gif", "Wednesday.gif",
                            "Thursday.gif", "Friday.gif", "Weekend.gif"];
            var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
            "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
            var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
            var dateObject = new Date();

            var current_image = daily_images[dateObject.getDay()];
            var currentday = days[dateObject.getDay()];
            var currentmonth = months[dateObject.getMonth()];

            var table_content = "<table border='1' cellpadding='5'>"
            table_content += "<tr><td width='100'>" + currentday + 
            "</td><td><img src='" + current_image + "' /></td></tr></table>";
            table_content += "<p>Today is " + currentday + ", " + currentmonth +
                " " + dateObject.getDate() + "</p>";
            return table_content;
        }

        function insert_title_rules_and_image(){
            var table_content = "<h2>TRU Student Union Daily Schedule</h2>";
            table_content += "<hr /><img src='Events.gif' /><hr />";
            return table_content;
        }
        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = determine_picture_day_and_month();
    </script>
</html>
```

Johannes answered this question.  The correct embedded style is below:

```
     <style>
        p {text-align: center;}
        table { margin: auto;}
        body img{display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
        h2 {text-align: center; color: red;}
    </style>
```

Comment: margin auto wont  work if you don't have fixed width of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to assign `display: block` to a `table`element is contrary to what tables are usually used for - `tr` and `td` elements inside that table most likely won't behave as they behave in a regular table. So I would suggest to erase `display: block` from the CSS for `table`

Second, to (horizontally) center any inline or inline-block elements (including images) *within*  a table or block element, you can use `text-align: center` for that element.

To center another block element inside a block element, you should define a fixed width and `margin: 0 auto` for the child element.